# Firebase crashes with 'listen() called twice for the same query' error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was trying to follow the advice and remove the listener when needed and register the listener when needed. So in my UIViewController.viewDidAppear I have the following:

```
let chatRef = messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(chat.objectId!)
var query = chatRef.queryOrderedByChild("createdAt")
if let since = since {
    query = query.queryStartingAtValue(since.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
}
let handle = query.observeEventType(FEventType.ChildAdded, withBlock: completion, withCancelBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
    println("error listening for new Chat messages: \(error)")
});
```

In my UIViewController.viewWillDisappear() I have

```
let chatRef = messagesRef.childByAppendingPath(chat.objectId!)
if chatRef != nil {
    chatRef.removeAllObservers()
}
```

But the program crashes every time the ViewController is entered the second time (going to the view controller, navigate away, then come back) with the following error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FPersistentConnection listen:tagId:hashFn:onComplete:], /Users/mtse/Dev/firebase/firebase-client-objc/Firebase/Firebase/Core/FPersistentConnection.m:127
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'listen() called twice for the same query'
```

The program runs fine if I don't remove the observers and call observeEventType only once in `viewDidLoad` instead of viewDidAppear.

The program also runs fine even if I remove the observer then add it back if I don't do `queryOrderedByChild` and `queryStartingAtValue`.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Firebase*

Listeners in Firebase are specific to the path or query that you register them on. Calling `removeAllObservers()` removes all observers, but **only from that path**.

So in your `viewWillDisappear()` you will need to remove the listeners from the query, instead of the ref.

```
query.removeAllObservers()
```

We just made this more explicit in our documentation and are looking at ways to make the API more intuitive.

### Update (20150724)

It turns out that calling `removeAllObservers()` on a `FFirebase` should remove all observers on queries on that same location too. It will not remove observers at `child()` locations, but should have worked in your case.

We are investigating what is going wrong, but it seems you have hit a bug in our iOS SDK. Once we find it, we'll release a fixed version. In the meantime the above serves (and will continue to serve) as a valid workaround.

Comment: it works now. thanks! So if I don't use query, I should call `Firebase.removeAllObservers()`, if I do use query, I should call `FQuery.removeAllObservers()` and never both. Is that correct? (The program seems to crash as well if I do both)

Comment: You need to remove all observers on each `FQuery` and each `Firebase` where you register observers. So if you register observers on both, you need to remove them on both. But your snippet only observes on the query, so you only have to call `query.removeAllObservers()`.

Comment: I am still experiencing this issue. Is there a fix for it?? I have tried calling removeAllObservers on all of my queries and references but I still get the same error.